# How can i list all the S3 buckets with some specific tag using cli?

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

Am trying to get all the S3 buckets with the **environment and service tag.** I have almost 200 buckets...How can i do that...Pls help me

```
aws s3api list-buckets
```

The above command listing all the bucket name with the creation date...How can i list all the bucket with the specific tags. I searched so many blogs but i couldn't get the exact command to get the bucket with the tags.I tried using with the jq command like

```
aws s3api list-buckets | jq .Buckets[].Name
```

am getting the following error:

```
Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0
```

My output for aws s3api list-buckets

```
2019-01-24T04:53:07.000Z |  aws-xxx              ||
||  2019-02-18T18:33:15.000Z |  aws-yyy
```

Comment: @cyrus It is listing all the buckets with the creation date

Answer (score 3):

You should be using the "get-bucket-tagging" api to get the tags associated with your bucket.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/get-bucket-tagging.html

I've found a simple script in github for doing this job . I hope this works for you.

https://gist.github.com/filipenf/0528d26f0dba78b72b39

Comment: @vinu...I tried that scrpt but am getting the error like Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0 if i run  aws s3api list-buckets | jq .Buckets[].Name

Comment: @ShwetthaRR i dont know what could be the cause but i suspect i could be a version mismatch as the script works fine for me. let me know the jq, uname  -r and the shell version. i'll try if i can reproduce

Comment: jq version is jq-1.5 am using centos 7

Answer (score 1):

If you goal is to find resources (eg Amazon EC2 instance, Amazon S3 buckets) that have specific tags, please look at [What Is AWS Resource Groups?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ARG/latest/userguide/welcome.html):

> You can use resource groups to organize your AWS resources. Resource groups make it easier to manage and automate tasks on large numbers of resources at one time. This guide shows you how to create and manage resource groups in AWS Resource Groups.

Comment: I need to list all the bucket with the environment and service tags...I need to do it with the cli

Comment: You appear to be asking many questions with similar requirements. You should instead look at using Resource Groups, which can provide this type of information on many different resources at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a sensible way to do this, I don't think you can even search by tags in the UI.

But you can do something like

```
s3_buckets_with_cache() {
  local S3CACHE JSONBUCKETS bucketwithtags tags
  S3CACHE="${DIR_CACHE}/s3buckets.json"
  if [[ ! -f ${S3CACHE} ]]; then
    JSONBUCKETS='{"buckets":[]}'
    IFS=$'\n'
    for bucket in $(aws s3api list-buckets | jq .Buckets[].Name -r); do
      tags=$(aws s3api get-bucket-tagging --bucket "${bucket}" 2>/dev/null)
      # shellcheck disable=SC2181
      [[ "$?" -ne 0 ]] && continue
      tags=$(echo "${tags}" | jq -c '.[][] | {(.Key): .Value}' | jq --slurp .)
      [[ "${tags}" == "[]" ]] && continue
      bucketwithtags="{\"bucket\": \"${bucket}\", \"tags\" : ${tags} }"
      JSONBUCKETS=$(echo "${JSONBUCKETS}" | jq ".buckets += [${bucketwithtags}]")
    done
    echo "${JSONBUCKETS}" >"${S3CACHE}"
  fi
  cat "${S3CACHE}"
}
```

And then call that with

```
AWS_BUCKET_NAME=$(s3_buckets_with_cache | jq -r '.buckets[] 
  | select(.tags[].foo == "bar" and .tags[].abc == "xyz") | .bucket')
```

Although this does not have cache invalidation or anything like that but you could easily check the timestamp of the file and invalidate it that way.

And I only added the cache because I had to crawl 3000 buckets for their tags and I don't want to do that every time I need to get a bucket name by tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by AWS `resource-groups` CLI

Example: https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/resource-groups/search-resources.html#examples

But the web UI seems more powerful which consists of link to each resource and export option to csv.
https://console.aws.amazon.com/resource-groups/tag-editor/find-resources